# Use a project as a maven dependency for another

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

Note: My title may look similar to other questions but couldn't get a neat workable answer to it.

I have two projects - P1 and P2.

P1 uses P2 as a maven dependency. Currently, P2 is installed in .m2 directory. What I want is to be able to point actual P2 source instead of the one in .m2 so that whenever I make changes in P2 code, I am able to see its impact immediately during debugging.

Any solution which is about making changes in files will be preferable over using some advanced Eclipse feature with lots of options.

[Update]:

I am using Intellij as the IDE. I can't see Workspace resolution but I tried adding P2 as a module in P1 and I could insert a breakpoint in P2 and the debug execution did stop at that but this doesn't solve the problem. If I make any changes and put a breakpoint, it says the class file is not in synch.

e.g. I modified another dependency P3 which P2 depends on. I have added P3 too as a module in project P1. Whenever I make changes to P3, compile and run, the changes don't seem to reflect. the IDE did show me that there are multiple alternative sources available and I made it point to my local repo instead of maven repo.

Comment: Just after posting this, I was able to achieve it by adding P2 as a module in P1 project. After that, when I executed P1 in debug mode, it asked me to choose between .m2/repository/P2 or actual P2 source that I added as submodule. I would still like to have a non-Eclipse kind of solution where I can make changes in a file.

Comment: With frameworks like maven and eclipse, you have basically two options: You do things exactly the way they expect you to do them, whether it's what you would prefer or not, or you become sufficiently expert in them that "advanced feature with lots of options" doesn't scare you.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, you can use "Workspace Resolution", which can be activated in the Maven preferences. If you change the source code and save (Eclipse compiles in the background), the results will be updated.

I don't know of any non-IDE approach to this problem because Maven itself requires you to install an artifact to make it usable for compilation of other artifacts.

Comment: I am using Intellij as the IDE. I cant see Workspace resolution but I tried adding P2 as a module in P1 and I could insert a breakpoint in P2. I have another problem where there's P3 which P2 depends on. I have added P3 too as a module in project P1. Whenever I make changes to P3, compile and run, the changes don't seem to reflect. the IDE did show me that there are multiple alternative sources available and I made it point to my local repo instead of maven repo.

Comment: You should only construct modules, if your projects all belong together and you want to compile and deploy them together. If you just want to achieve "instant compiling", you shouldn't just add modules. They are meant to structure projects in several subprojects.